# Iterate all JSON objct and put into html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I need to loop all the json object and frame into html. I can iterate all the json object but I could not get only one json object(first json object).

```
var res = '[{"ID":"246","mobile":"samsung","feedback":"feedback goes here"},{"ID":"1485","mobile":"Moto","feedback":"feedback goes here"},{"ID":"6982","mobile":"iPhone","feedback":"feedback goes here"}]';
obj = JSON.parse(res);
console.log('response length:' + obj.length);
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var finalResult = "";
    var objects = obj[i];
    for (var key in objects) {
        var res = "<tr><td>" + objects.ID + "</td><td>" + objects.mobile + "</td><td>" + objects.feedback + "</td><td></tr>";
        console.log('res:' + res);
        finalResult = res.concat(res);
        console.log('finalResult:' + finalResult);
    }
}
```

And i am unable to put everything into 'tr' element since javascript doest not have stringbuffer. I think it can be by using StringBuffer in java. How can it be done using javascript/jquery?

Pls help me.

Comment: Please note: `var obj = obj[i];`!! you are redefining obj in the middle of your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do this:

```
var res = '[{"ID":"246","mobile":"samsung","feedback":"feedback goes here"},{"ID":"1485","mobile":"Moto","feedback":"feedback goes here"},{"ID":"6982","mobile":"iPhone","feedback":"feedback goes here"}]';
obj = JSON.parse(res);
console.log('response length:' + obj.length);
var finalResult = "";
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {  
    var str1 = "aasd";
    var obj1 = obj[i];
    for (var key in obj1) {
        var res = "<tr><td>" + obj1.ID + "</td><td>" + obj1.mobile + "</td><td>" + obj1.feedback + "</td><td></tr>";
        //console.log('res:' + res);
        finalResult += res;
    }
}
console.log('finalResult:' + finalResult);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are redefining obj in the middle of your code:

```
 var obj = obj[i];
```

Use another name:

You are also resetting your finalResult inside the loop (and the inner loop is not required):

http://jsfiddle.net/7j52myca/

```
var res = '[{"ID":"246","mobile":"samsung","feedback":"feedback goes here"},{"ID":"1485","mobile":"Moto","feedback":"feedback goes here"},{"ID":"6982","mobile":"iPhone","feedback":"feedback goes here"}]';
var phones = JSON.parse(res);
console.log('response length:' + phones.length);
var finalResult = "";
for (var i = 0; i < phones.length; i++) {
    var str1 = "aasd";
    var obj = phones[i];
    var res = "<tr><td>" + obj.ID + "</td><td>" + obj.mobile + "</td><td>" + obj.feedback + "</td><td></tr>";
    console.log('res:' + res);
    finalResult += res;
}
console.log('finalResult:' + finalResult);
$('#result').append(finalResult);
```

You can do the same thing a lot shorter using pure jQuery, but @Rory McCrossan has already posted a good version like that so I will not bother adding one here.

Comment: i used another var name ...Now i can iterate all the json object. But unable to append all the json object. I am expecting final result as  finalResult:
<tr><td>246</td><td>samsung</td><td>feedback goes here</td><td>
<tr><td>1485</td><td>Moto</td><td>feedback goes here</td><td></tr>
<tr><td>6982</td><td>iPhone</td><td>feedback goes here</td><td></tr>. How to append all the things into one?

Comment: @ezhil: That is not clear... Are you wanting to create a single string to append to speed up the append. Your code is also reinitialising `finalResult` inside the loop. Try one of the other simpler jQuery answer instead :)

Comment: Updated to include the other 2 issues for you.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you're redefining the variable you're looping over, `obj`, within the iterating function.

As you've tagged this using jQuery, so here's a shorter alternative using `$.each` to build the table:

```js
var res = '[{"ID":"246","mobile":"samsung","feedback":"feedback goes here"},{"ID":"1485","mobile":"Moto","feedback":"feedback goes here"},{"ID":"6982","mobile":"iPhone","feedback":"feedback goes here"}]';
var phones = JSON.parse(res);

$.each(phones, function(i, obj) {
    $('<tr />')
        .append('<td>' + obj.ID + '</td><td>' + obj.mobile + '</td><td>' + obj.feedback + '</td><td>')
        .appendTo('table');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

Comment: hey i am not copying your answer,but i would like to give you credits

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the inner for loop, you can access your elements directly. I made a couple of other changes as well that can be found below:

```js
var res = '[{"ID":"246","mobile":"samsung","feedback":"feedback goes here"},{"ID":"1485","mobile":"Moto","feedback":"feedback goes here"},{"ID":"6982","mobile":"iPhone","feedback":"feedback goes here"}]';

obj = JSON.parse(res);
var finalResult = "";

console.log('response length:' + obj.length);

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

    var str1 = "aasd";
    
    var tableRow = "<tr><td>" + obj[i]["ID"] + "</td><td>" + obj[i]["mobile"] + "</td><td>" + obj[i]["feedback"] + "</td><td></tr>";

    finalResult += tableRow;

}

console.log('finalResult:' + finalResult);
```

I hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery each method you can do it

```js
var res = '[{"ID":"246","mobile":"samsung","feedback":"feedback goes here"},{"ID":"1485","mobile":"Moto","feedback":"feedback goes here"},{"ID":"6982","mobile":"iPhone","feedback":"feedback goes here"}]';
obj = JSON.parse(res);

var finalResult = "";
$.each(obj, function(i, item) {

  var res = "<tr><td>" + item.ID + "</td><td>" + item.mobile + "</td><td>" + item.feedback + "</td><td></tr>";
  console.log('res:' + res);
  finalResult += res;
});
$('body').append(finalResult)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

see this code

```
var jsonobj = '[{"ID":"246","mobile":"samsung","feedback":"feedback goes here"},{"ID":"1485","mobile":"Moto","feedback":"feedback goes here"},{"ID":"6982","mobile":"iPhone","feedback":"feedback goes here"}]';
obj = JSON.parse(jsonobj);
alert(obj);
$.each(obj, function (index, item) {

    $('<tr/>')
        .append('<td>' + item.ID + '</td><td>' + item.mobile + '</td><td>' + item.feedback + '</td><td>')
        .appendTo('table');

});
```

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/21wrqrfb/